# Clicking on TextField while it has focus does not show keyboard in jetpack compose Android

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-jetpack

I am creating an android application jetpack compose. I implemented a TextField like this :

```
fun NameViewer(nameState: MutableState<String>) {

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)) {
        Text(text = "Item Name:", modifier = Modifier.width(104.dp))
        TextField(
            value = nameState.value,
            onValueChange = { if (it.length <= 15) nameState.value = it },
            placeholder = { Text("Enter name") },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
}
```

When I click on the TextField first time, keyboard shows up as expected, then if I press back button the keyboard hides as expected, but if I click on the TextField again, the keyboard doesn't show up. It only shows up if I click on another TextField and then click on the previous TextField. Same behavior is shown by all the TextFields in the activity. Here is the full code of the activity

**Update**
I did some more testing and now Now I am absolutely certain that the problem is is some incompatibility in dependencies. So here are my gradle files

Module level

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.wastesamaritanassignment1"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.wastesamaritanassignment1"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))

    val roomVersion = "2.6.1"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$roomVersion")

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.5.0")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.5.4")

    implementation("androidx.paging:paging-compose:3.2.1")

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta01")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Top level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

Can someone please tell me how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the the problem. It was the beta material 3 library of jetpack compose that was causing the issue.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta01")
```

So I changed it to

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
```

which solved the issue.